# Selenium dynamically iterate through table

Tags: selenium

So I've been beating my brow trying to find a dynamic method through selenium of iterating through a table and gathering specific values from that table, to create a mapping from a remote service to a local data label. Here's the code that I'm trying to iterate through, and these lengths may change:

```
        string Fee1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");
        string CCFee1 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");

        string Fee2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[2]//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");
        string CCFee2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[2]/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");

        string Fee3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[3]//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");
        string CCFee3 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[3]/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");

        string Fee4 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[4]//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");
        string CCFee4 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[4]/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");

        string Fee5 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[5]//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");
        string CCFee5 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[5]/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");

        string Fee6 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[6]//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");
        string CCFee6 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr[6]/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");
```

I'm sure there is a way to iterate through the table, gathering the values, in a dynamic fashion, such that there should only be a necessity for:

string Fee**"x"** = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");

string CCFee**"x"** = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");

Where "x" is increasing to the end of the table, and also, the  should be dynamic also, starting with the second line, as such:

string Fee2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr__[2]__//input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");

string CCFee2 = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr__[2]__/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title");

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, assuming that you only have one table on the page, you could do something like this (not tested, or exact syntax since I don't know C#):

```
List<WebElement> allRows = driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//tr"));
int RowIndex = 0;
for (aRow in allRows) {
    fee = aRow.FindElement(By.XPath("/input[@id='fees']")).GetAttribute("title");
    ccFee = aRow.FindElementBy.XPath("/td[3]/select")).GetAttribute("title")
    RowIndex += RowIndex;
    // store your fee and ccFee in some map, or some other structure
    // based on the RowIndex
}
```